# How to validate the password at DB level in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to register a user with a phone and password, I want to find if the user exists and if the password is the same as we have already on our DB then I want the user to get a login instead of giving an error to that the user with same creds already exists.

Now the problem I cant validate the password.

I'm trying :

```
registered_user = CustomUser.objects.get(phone_number=data['phone_number'])
if make_password(data['password']) == registered_user.passwrod:
                serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(registered_user, many=False)
                return Response(serializer.data)
```

But I get

```
registered_user has no attribute password
```

How we can fix this?

Comment: Typo `passwrod` to `password`. But this will not work: you need to `.check_password(..)`.

Comment: Thanks , for comment, `.check_password(..)` works. after fixing the typo.